# wxPython app is frozen until request is done

Tags: python, python-requests, wxpython

I have the following method that's supposed to update the UI of my `wxPython` application when a checkbox is checked, and THEN make a network request. The problem is, if the network request is included in the `checkboxChecked` function, it causes the UI to stall until the request is done. Is there any way to update the UI, and then make the request?

```
def checkboxChecked(self, event, completion):

    # UI Updates
    isChecked = self.readBox.GetValue()
    self.isReadJSON[str(self.currentChapter)]["read"] = isChecked
    self.setWordsReadLabelText()

    # Network Request
    completion
```

Comment: I think you want `wx.CallAfter`.  It allows whatever is currently going on to complete, then invokes your function (in this case the network request).  There's also `wx.CallLater` that takes a timeout if you want to wait some specified time before making the network call.

Comment: I tried wx.CallAfter(completion) but it has the same problem. However, wx.CallLater(1, completion) seems to work!

Answer (score 0):

Using `wx.CallLater(1, completion)` keeps the UI from freezing up by performing the network request 1 millisecond later.